# Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getUsedProducts() in app\...\.Configurable\Attribute\Collection.php on line 160

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

I Try to make a link in my custom module where I can show my all product with some information. But It show a error.
There just install magento with sample data. my output

337-Aviator Sunglasses(ace000)
338-Jackie O Round Sunglasses(ace001)

.....

.....

.....

399-Madison 8GB Digital Media Player(hde012)

400-Compact mp3 Player(hde013)

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getUsedProducts() in \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute\Collection.php on line 160**

My code

*config.xml*

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abdus_Allproduct>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Abdus_Allproduct>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <allproduct>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Abdus_Allproduct</module>
                    <frontName>allproduct</frontName>
                </args>
            </allproduct>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

*IndexController.php*

```
<?php
  class Abdus_Allproduct_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
      public function indexAction(){
          $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $col=$collection->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',array('in'=>array(2,3,4)));
            foreach($col as $c){
                $collection->load($c->getId());
                echo $collection->getId().'-'.$collection->getName().'('.$collection->getSku().')<br>'; 
            }
      }
  }
```

Comment: when you are got error ?

Comment: where you have use getUsedProducts() function?

Comment: When I click my link
http://example.com/allproduct/

Comment: please share your code where you have use this  function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try bellow code

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',array('in'=>array(2,3,4)));
    foreach($collection as $product){
        echo $product->getId().'-'.$product->getName().'('.$product->getSku().')<br>'; 
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you use

       `->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite()`
I need all product without any filter.

Comment: for the product price with tax or not taxable product and product url

Comment: if you are use above then output :: [price] => 1.0000
            [final_price] => 1.0000
            [minimal_price] => 1.0000
            [min_price] => 1.0000
            [max_price] => 1.0000
            [tier_price] => 
            [visibility] => 4
            [small_image] => no_selection
            [thumbnail] => no_selection
            [name] => COIN,NAVY W/BOX DG110
            [url_key] => coin-navy-w-box-dg110
            [request_path] => coin-navy-w-box-dg110.html

Comment: Otherwise, you don't get below fields in the output
[final_price] => 1.0000
            [minimal_price] => 1.0000
            [min_price] => 1.0000
            [max_price] => 1.0000
            [tier_price] => 
            [request_path] => coin-navy-w-box-dg110.html